# how do I specify a transparent background colour on a draw2d Figure?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, draw2d

I'm writing an eclipse plugin, and I'm layering some simple figures (i.e. view elements) together to create diagrams.

A simple component looks like this

[A simple component with rendering issues http://img115.yfrog.com/img115/4946/componentwithopacity.jpg](http://img115.yfrog.com/img115/4946/componentwithopacity.jpg)

The drum icon on the right is part of a tiny widget drawer.

And the incomplete line underneath it is trying to represent multiplicity, but it's being blocked by the widget drawer.

I tried really hard to get a transparent background on the Figure, but the SWT colour class has no way to specify an alpha or transparent colour.

has anyone run into this problem before? How can I make my draw2d Figure background transparent so I can see stuff behind it.

This a small example of various other opacity related issues I've encountered. Solving this would fix a wide range of visual issues.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
CV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So `IFigure.setOpaque(false)` doesn't do it?

Comment: hahaha! I did try that! but I was using draw2d Panels, which override isOpaque with always true. so setOpaque was getting ignored. I changed all my container Figures to just Figure and bam, the widget is see through! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Simply set the alpha from 0 to 255 to your liking.  See `Graphics#setAlpha(int)` during your paint event or see `Shape` - I think `setAlpha(int)` exists there too.